# Organizing screen with Windows keys

Tags: windows-10

I like to use the Windows key shortcuts for quickly organizing my on-screen windows.  However, it's got a very annoying side-effect that started a few months ago.  Often (but not always), after doing a window move that way I get popup a few seconds later of all my Windows.  Since it's delayed, I've usually already started typing again or have otherwise moved on with my work.  That popup will steal those keystrokes and do all kinds of wacky things to my display based on what I'd started typing...

Is there some way to turn off that annoying popup so that the Windows organizing keys *only* organize the windows and do NOT also sometimes trigger that popup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out.  It's the Windows Snap feature doing this to me.

- Open Settings
- Go to System
- Go to Multitasking
- Turn off "When I snap a window, show what I can snap next to it"